# OAUTH2: Storage('filename.data') doesn't create file (gspread, python)

Tags: python, json, gspread, oauth2client

I am trying to access a google sheet via python. So far, all the authentication and verification with my Google Account worked. But according to http://www.indjango.com/access-google-sheets-in-python-using-gspread/

```
storage=Storage('creds.data')
```

should create a file from which I can access the refresh_token. When executing my code however, after I get the **The authentication flow has completed** message in my Google Chrome, no file is being stored.
Here is my code

```
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2WebServerFlow
from oauth2client import tools
from oauth2client.file import Storage


CLIENT_ID = '<Client ID from Google API Console>'
CLIENT_SECRET = '<Client secret from Google API Console>'

flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(
      client_id = "contains my id",
      client_secret = "contains my secret",
      scope = 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds https://docs.google.com/feeds',
      redirect_uri = 'http://example.com/auth_return'
   )


storage = Storage('creds.data')
flags = tools.argparser.parse_args(args=[])
credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, storage, flags)
print("access_token: %s" % credentials.access_token)
```

Maybe I do not understand the Storage() class correctly? Does anyone know how do resolve that?

EDIT: Timeout error:

[image]

---

#### Resolved

It turned out, that the cause was the Internet access (probably firewall) at my workplace. Tried to run the code at home and it worked.

Comment: [tools.run_flow(flow, storage)](http://oauth2client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/oauth2client/tools.html) takes a flow argument, opens an authentication server page in the web browser, and if the user grants access, returns new credentials. The credentials are stored in the `storage` argument which **is supposed to** update the storage file. If you look at the end of the source code, `storage.put(credential)` occurs.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! Upon reading the tools.run_flow() I thought to let the program run for a while. Even though "The authentication flow has completed" message was displayed, after a minute or two I get a time out error. (EDIT in main post)